# Install4j: Executable file deleted when reboot was performed after the installation in Windows Server 2012 64bit

Tags: windows-server-2012, install4j

I generated the installer executable file in Windows 7 64-bit using install4j 6.1.1. Then the executable file was copied to a Windows server 2012 machine and the software was installed. After the installation, the windows was rebooted (no requirement of my software installation process) at any random time, but after the reboot, the installer file vanished! I have retested it keeping the installer in different locations but every time I install the software and then  perform a reboot, weirdly the installer is deleted.

Following is the media-file setting inside the install4j project:

```
<windows name="Windows-64" id="24" customizedId="win64" mediaFileName="${compiler:sys.shortName}_${compiler:sys.version}_Windows_x64" installDir="/backend" overridePrincipalLanguage="false" jreBitType="64" runPostProcessor="false" postProcessor="" failOnPostProcessorError="false" useLegacyMediaFileIds="false" legacyMediaFileIds="" downloadURL="" includeAllDownloadableComponents="false" includedJRE="resources/windows-amd64-1.7.0_79" manualJREEntry="false" bundleType="1" jreURL="" jreShared="false" directDownload="false" installOnlyIfNecessary="false" customInstallBaseDir="C:/" contentFilesType="1" verifyIntegrity="true">
  <excludedComponents />
  <includedDownloadableComponents />
  <excludedLaunchers />
  <excludedBeans>
    <bean refId="3770" />
    <bean refId="3771" />
    <bean refId="1594" />
    <bean refId="3772" />
    <bean refId="1737" />
    <bean refId="3773" />
  </excludedBeans>
  <overriddenPrincipalLanguage id="en" customLocalizationFile="" />
  <exclude>
    <entry location="admin/bin/teamviewer_11.0.57095.i686.rpm" fileType="regular" />
    <entry location="bin/fpcsctl" fileType="regular" />
    <entry location=".i4j_external_105/sql/initDB.sh" fileType="regular" />
    <entry location=".i4j_external_105/temp/jdk1.7.0_79_linux-32.zip" fileType="regular" />
    <entry location=".i4j_external_105/temp/jdk-7u79-windows-x32.zip" fileType="regular" />
    <entry location=".i4j_external_105/temp/postgresql-9.4.6-linux-32.zip" fileType="regular" />
    <entry location=".i4j_external_105/temp/postgresql-9.4.6-linux-64.zip" fileType="regular" />
    <entry location=".i4j_external_105/temp/postgresql-9.4.6-windows-x86.zip" fileType="regular" />
    <entry location=".i4j_external_105/temp/vcredist_x86.exe" fileType="regular" />
    <entry location=".i4j_external_105/temp/jdk1.7.0_79_linux-64.zip" fileType="regular" />
    <entry location=".i4j_external_105/temp/librxtxSerial.so" fileType="regular" />
    <entry location=".i4j_external_105/temp/librxtxParallel.so" fileType="regular" />
  </exclude>
  <variables />
  <autoUpdate useMinUpdatableVersion="false" minUpdatableVersion="" useMaxUpdatableVersion="false" maxUpdatableVersion="">
    <commentFiles />
    <customAttributes />
  </autoUpdate>
</windows>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug that was fixed in install4j 6.1.2.

Comment: just out of curiosity, if it is not too complex, what was the reason for the file delete?